# Shortest Pig script that will use Accumulator

Tags: apache-pig, udf

I'm adding an Accumulator implementation to a Pig UDF, and I want to test it.

What is the shortest and simplest Pig script that will use the accumulator?

For simplicity's sake, assume that it will load a file with *N* integers, where *N* > *pig.accumulative.batchsize* so that the accumulate() method will be called more than once.

```
data = LOAD 'input' AS (val1:int);

output = ... (code which uses the UDF comes here)

STORE output INTO 'output';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is sufficient:

```
data = LOAD 'input' AS (val1:int);

output = FOREACH (group d all) GENERATE ACCUMULATIVE_UDF(val1);

STORE output INTO 'output';
```